# Is it a good idea to design database with inheritance?

Tags: sql, database, inheritance, database-design

For example, I have 2 tables : 'customer' and 'staff'. They are almost the same, only 2 attributes are different. So should I create another table named 'person' contains all of the same attributes of 'customer' and 'staff' then create fk keys point to this 'person'? Something like inheritance in class design.

Is there any drawback to this method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're describing a pattern call [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).  It's a valid design, but like any other design, it must be used with good judgment.  Read Martin Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" for more details on its advantages and disadvantages.

Some people caution against the use of joins, but you need a join only when you need the subclass-specific columns.  When a given query only needs the common columns, you can avoid the extra join.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a drawback to that method. Joins increase query complexity (immensely so in some cases) and can increase query time if you're not careful.

Instead, the standard way to do this (i.e. simulate object inheritance when only a few attributes differ between the subclasses) is to do something called [Single Table Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance). This method prevents database joins at the cost of a little bit of unused database space.

It works like this: You create one table that contains all the attributes, including the ones that only apply to one or the other, as well as a `type` attribute to specify the object type. For example, if `customer` has attributes:

`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `order_date`

AND `staff` has attributes:

`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `hire_date`

Then you create one table with columns for all the attributes and a type:

`id`, `type`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `order_date`, `hire_date`

The `type` column will always contain either "customer" or "staff". If `type` is "customer", then `hire_date` is always NULL, and is meaningless. If `type` is "staff" then `order_date` is always NULL, and is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, how about if I have other tables also have id, name, email, password but with some different specific attributes ?

Comment: @Sun, then just add in those specific attributes to the big list. For example, if you have a `administrator` type with id, name, email, password, and a unique field `permissions`, then your Single Table will contain id, type, name, email, password, order_date, hire_date, permissions. And now type can be "customer", "staff", or "administrator". The fields that don't apply to a particular type just remain NULL. Make sense?

Comment: I got it. But do you think there will be a lot of fields remain NULL in a row if we have many tables join into one like that.

Comment: @Sun, that's a decision you have to make based on your code. NULL rows are pretty cheap. But so are LEFT JOINs. You have to decide whether to go for JOIN complexity, or not proliferating any NULL columns. There's not a hard and fast rule for whether you should use Single Table Inheritance (as I describe) or Class Table Inheritance (as you describe); there's just a rule of thumb that if only a few fields are unique, STI is often a better solution.

Comment: Half our staff are also customers. I'm pretty sure that's true for most businesses. (But not for all of them.)

Comment: What about the idea of Keeping the same Column for Both Types but having a different meaning in the business logic?
For example 
id, type, name, email, password , TypeSpecificDate.

And on the Bussiness part handle logic 
If (Type=Customer)
 order_date = TypeSpecificDate
Else (Type=Staff)
 hire_date = TypeSpecificDate 

I know this is bad practice for someone looking at your database and you have to keep common constraints or none, but reduces your table size. And if you have multiple types that may share same types makes a flexible choice. I am having 19 Different types so that was a solution

Answer (score 4):

Both Pranay Rana and Ben Lee are correct, and the ultimate answer is: "it depends".

You have to weigh up the number of sub-class specific columns against the number of common columns to decide what's right for you. Single Table inheritance doesn't scale well: what happens when you have to introduce a third type of sub-class, such as suppliers?

For that matter how are you going to treat staff that are also customers?

Answer (score 4):

Lookup "generalization specialization relational modeling".  You'll find some good articles on the subject.  Most of the examples follow the same pattern as the Class Table Inheritance link that Bill gave you.

There's just one more little detail.  The specialized tables (for customer and staff in your case) do not autonumber their id fieid.  Instead, when you populate them, the id field should get a copy of the id field in the generalized table  (person in your case).

This makes the specialized ids do double duty.  They are both a pk and an fk reference to the corresponsding row in the genralized table.  This makes joins easier and faster.

It can be convenient to create views that have each specialized table joined with the generalized table.  Or you can make one large view that generates the same data you would see in a single table inheritance pattern suggested by another response.  It's basically a union of a bunch of joins.

Comment: Of course, there are 2 ids, one for the specialized table and one for fk to the generalized one.

Comment: No, there is one ID value. The point Walter Mitty is making (and it's a good one) is that they should be the *same* value, thus asserting a "might-have" relationship, rather than a "has-many". The super-class has an auto-number PK, the sub-classes share that PK.

Answer (score 2):

Well I say its good design because you are not repeating data and that's y the data normalization is there.

just one thing is that as much as you normalize your no of join will increase.

Comment: I disagree with this assessment. Yes, you're not repeating data, but as you point out yourself, you are proliferating `joins`. If only a few attributes differ, `Single Table Inheritance` is a much better solution, because avoids the `joins`, while also not repeating any data.

Comment: @Ben Lee - well it depend on the how you view it and how large data is but i surely go with OP design, design suggest by you is also good one but it depends on the situation we are...thanks

Comment: you're right, it depends on the specific situation. But assuming only a few unique rows, I think STI is better. I admit this could just be my own preferential bias leaking into the analysis.

Comment: One possible drawback of the Single Table Inheritance: in the proposed example, if one of the staff members ever buys something from the company he will become a customer... assuming you have a "type" field in your Big Table Inheritance, what type do you use? Staff? Customer? StaffCustomer? BTI works best when there is absolutely no risk of one entity belonging to more than one "class". Otherwise you start putting flags all over the place and stuff like select * from BigTable where type="STAFF" becomes cumbersome....